# Need knowledge about SharePoint

Tags: asp.net, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am web developer specifically from Microsoft background. I have experience in ASP.NET MVC and other JS frameworks. Now point is, I want to learn Share Point. But honestly, I don't have any idea of it. What problems it solves and how much it is beneficial? I have Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2008 Express - Are these software are sufficient to start building a SharePoint application?

Can someone here please brief me on below points

- Usage and benefits of Share Point
- Software requirements

Answer (score -1):

SharePoint is a big platform and the benefits are that you get lots of functionality for "free" without the need for traditional developer skills.  In short you are getting a platform that offers multiple pluggable authentication, a flexible way for end users to create "tables" of data with user defined schema, a ACL model for that data and a forms model for all that data.  On top of all that there is an API model for all of that plus lots and lots of other features.

That's the big benefit of SharePoint...lots of things are built into the platform and the developer story is about extending those things to do more.  The challenge of course is that there is lots to learn in the platform and you don't really want to fight against the goals of platform, but that is often hard to grok when you are just starting out.